# What is the vantage of asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, migration

What is the vantage of asp.net mvc?

How can I migrate from asp.net to asp.net mvc?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541957/what-are-the-features-and-advantages-of-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to realize that it's a completely different model to that of ASP.NET WebForms. The one doesn't replace the other.

From the ASP.NET MVC Site

- Provides complete control over your
  HTML markup
- Enables rich AJAX integration
- Intuitive website URLs
- Clear separation of concerns which
  results in web applications that are
  easier to maintain and extend over
  time.
- Testability – including support for
  test-driven development.